# No provider for NavParams error is coming In Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am transferring parameters from one component to app.component.ts but the error is coming. Error: No provider for NavParams.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```js
import { FrontPage } from "./../pages/front/front";
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Nav, Platform, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
import { HomePage } from "../pages/home/home";
import { ListPage } from "../pages/list/list";
import { ProductPage } from "../pages/product/product";
import { LoginpagePage } from "../pages/loginpage/loginpage";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "app.html",
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  menuclick: boolean = true;
  menuclick2: boolean = false;
  rootPage: any = FrontPage;
  uname: string;

  pages: Array<{ title: string; component: any; name2: string }>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    public navParams: NavParams
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.uname = this.navParams.get("param1");
    this.pages = [
      { title: "Home", component: FrontPage, name2: "home" },
      { title: "Product Categories", component: ProductPage, name2: "basket" },
      { title: "Merchandise", component: ProductPage, name2: "man" },
      { title: "My Orders", component: ProductPage, name2: "cart" },
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  loginpage2() {
    this.nav.push(LoginpagePage);
  }

  logoutClicked() {
    console.log("Logout");
    this.nav.pop();
  }
}
```

In this component, I am getting the navparam value like this this.uname = this.navParams.get('param1');

This is my **loginpage.ts**:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  IonicPage,
  NavController,
  NavParams,
  AlertController,
} from "ionic-angular";
import { RestapiProvider } from "../../providers/restapi/restapi";
import { ListPage } from "../list/list";
import { FrontPage } from "../front/front";
import { CartPage } from "./../cart/cart";
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { MyApp } from "./../../app/app.component";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-loginpage",
  templateUrl: "loginpage.html",
})
export class LoginpagePage {
  todo: FormGroup;
  responseData: any;
  userData = { username: "", password: "" };
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public restProvider: RestapiProvider,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("ionViewDidLoad LoginpagePage");
  }

  getloginUsers() {
    this.restProvider
      .getUsers(this.userData, "user_Login")
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
          this.responseData = data;
          console.log(this.responseData.msg.name);
          if (this.responseData.status === "success") {
            this.navCtrl.push(MyApp, {
              param1: this.responseData.msg.name,
            });
          } else {
            this.presentAlert();
          }
        }
      });
  }

  presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Incorrect Username Or Password",
      buttons: ["Dismiss"],
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  cardpage2() {
    this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
  }
}
```

Error: No provider for NavParams is coming. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Often this error occurs when you have not provided the service in a provider array. Please check the it out

Comment: @AnkurShah . providers: [ NavParams ], I have added this in the app.module.ts.

Comment: @AnkurShah . Can you please provide the answer for that. Please.

Comment: @AnkurShah. After importing this error is coming. Can't resolve all parameters for NavParams: (?).

Comment: @Ragav Can you please provide the sample source project which is giving u an error

Comment: In this, when I am trying to pass the value from the loginpage.ts to the App.component.ts, it is giving the above error. param1: this.responseData.msg.name,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that, The app.component.ts is the first thing rendered in your app. You can't navigate to it, obviously, you can't receive params.

**The First Solution is that:** I have to use a provider to store your user data, and then set your side menu data from the provider.

**The Second Solution is that:** To Use events as below.

By using events, I have solved my problem and my event code is working fine.

```js
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// second page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you please try adding.Hope it might work. If you provide me a project i can help you in a better manner.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'page-loginpage',
 templateUrl: 'loginpage.html',
 providers: [NavParams]
})
```

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Error. Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; provider: (typeof NavParams)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'provider' does not exist in type 'Component'. Did you mean to write 'providers'? [2345]

Comment: Should I provide my anydesk ID.

Comment: I think, it should be providers.

Comment: After adding it, it is showing error. Can't resolve all parameters for NavParams: (?).

Comment: please provide me whole project. so that i can solve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186707/discussion-between-raghav-and-ankur-shah).

Comment: How to provide the full project? On github it will be fine.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: The interaction is between login page and the app.component.ts.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution
Instead of adding `navParams` in `constructor`

Add `public navParams = new NavParams`

For example

```js
export class LoginpagePage {
  public navParams = new NavParams();
  todo: FormGroup;
  responseData: any;
  userData = { username: "", password: "" };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I had to do two things to fix it:

- Remove the modal route entry from the app-routing-module.ts
- update the following entry in  the Modal's Module like this:

```js
@NgModule({
     imports: [
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule,
       IonicModule
       ],
     declarations: [DetailsPage],
  entryComponents:[DetailsPage]
})

export class DetailsPageModule {}
```

With these two changes I was able to use navParams like this inside de Modal ts file:

```js
ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.selectedItem = this.navParams.get('selectedItem');
   console.log(this.selectedItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The query parameter is simply retrieved using the `ActivatedRoute` interface from `'@angular/router'`:

```js
public constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.firstname = params["param1"];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this variant

```js
const params = {
  phone,
  verificationId,
};
this.navCtrl.navigateForward("/forward-page", { state: params });
```

and in forward-page

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
    const state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
    if (state) {
        this.phone = state.phone;
        this.verificationId = state.verificationId;
    }
}
```

works great

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported the ionic angular module in your @NgModule?

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {

    })
  ],
```

Comment: imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ], I have imported this in app.module.ts.

Comment: Do I have to import the Login component also?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (ionic7) was using the Angular way:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
    constructor(
        private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activeRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            if (paramMap.has('id')) {            
                this.id = paramMap.get('id');
            }
        });
    }
```